# Create a Kivy based GoogleCloudMessaging client

Tags: google-play-services, kivy

I am trying to create a kivy-based GoogleCloudMessaging client.

Comparing the permissions given to the app in [google example client](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html), to those in the  `AndroidManifest.xml` generated by buildozer for me, I have seen that mine does not have the line.

```
<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

It does however include the line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

where, of course, com.example.gcm is replaced with the contents of `package.domain`.`package.name` from my buildozer spec.

Can anyone tell me...

1) What does the line that is missing from my AndroidManifest.xml do?

2) How do I best add it? The AndroidManifest.xml file is regenerated each time I build, right, so how would I make custom changes to it so that they don't get over written?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an attribute of the permission.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

> A permission that the system grants only if the requesting application
>   is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared
>   the permission. If the certificates match, the system automatically
>   grants the permission without notifying the user or asking for the
>   user's explicit approval.

It's not required - the default is "normal" and should work for you.  It's not included on Google's example setup for GCM either.